# Django template url tag

Tags: django

After reading many sources, I am confused about what should be inside `{% url "xxx" %}` (quotes for Django 1.5). Is it the path to a view function, or is it the name of a named url pattern?

Both seem to be correct, mentioned in different places in official Django documentation.

- [View function documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-url)
- [Named URL pattern documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in first link, both view function or url name pattern can be used in the `{%url%}` tag. And the whatever it is put that in quotes.

> Warning :
>
> Don’t forget to put quotes around the function path or pattern name!
>
> Changed in Django 1.5: The first parameter used not to be quoted,
>   which was inconsistent with other template tags. Since Django 1.5, it
>   is evaluated according to the usual rules: it can be a quoted string
>   or a variable that will be looked up in the context.